# TypeScript RxJS: Map to a single type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I need to map this array of union type `string | { field:string, asc: boolean }` to the second unioned type.

I mean:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';

var sortFields: Array<string | { field: string, direction: boolean }>;

from(sortFields)
    .map(sortField => {
        if (typeof(sortField) == "string")
            return { field: sortField, direction: true };
        else
            return { field: sortField.field, direction: sortField.direction };
    }
);
```

The above code doesn't quite work. It's telling me that `map` returns `Observable<{field:string, direction: boolean} | {field:string, direction: boolean}>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What RxJS version you're using? This should be inferred correctly by TypeScript but maybe in some older RxJS version that was a bug in generic typings.

Answer (score 0):

It works well with latest versions of typescript / rxjs

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

var sortFields: Array<string | { field: string, direction: boolean }> = [];

from(sortFields).pipe(
    map(sortField => {
        if (typeof(sortField) == "string")
            return { field: sortField, direction: true };
        else
            return { field: sortField.field, direction: sortField.direction };
    })
);
```